# Unexpected error while using the len statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve one of the katas in codewars. The code gives an unexpected error while using len statement. Please can someone help with this.

```
def scramble(s1,s2):
    j1=[i for i in s2 if i in s1]
    j1=j1.sort()
    s1=[x for x in s1]
    s1=s1.sort()
    if len(s1)==len(j1):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 1):

`list.sort()` returns `None`. Just call the sort like so:

```
s1.sort()
```

However, if you want to assign the sorted version of `s1`, use the `sorted` function:

```
s2 = sorted(s1)
```